# XMLHttpRequest cannot load for No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load a div using:

```
<script>
    $("#details").load('http://localhost:31075/ #user');
</script>
```

But getting acess restriction.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://`localhost`:31075/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://`localhost`:43302' is therefore not allowed access.

So how can I define access headers on the earlier page as that is also my MVC app.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to fetch data from server, JSONP could be a solution since it is very easy to implement.

If you want to be able to made not only GET, but also POST, PUT etc., you can use cross origin resource sharing, CORS on server. Since you didn't mention which server side language you have, have a look at [here](http://enable-cors.org/server.html). It contains some code snippets for various languages. Basically server needs to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header